# Ruby on Rails - Sidekiq undefined method `merge' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, production

My Sidekiq server suddenly doesn't want to run anymore and I can't explain myself why. This is the error message:

```
undefined method `merge' for #<String:0x007f1ac9aa1848>
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:366:in `parse_config'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:208:in `setup_options'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:39:in `parse'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.4/bin/sidekiq:11:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

I use the following command to start it:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -e production -P /home/deploy/rails_app/shared/pids/sidekiq.pid -c 8
```

You can find the sidekiq.yml file here: http://codepaste.net/rujg15.
Please help :(

Comment: Are you sure, you linked your `sidekiq.yml`? Because the linked file is a Bash script. It's actually the init script to start and stop the Sidekiq process on linux. If it is really the content your sidekiq.yml, that would explain the error.

Comment: You were right! This is so embarrassing! I accidentally pasted the wrong code there and on the next deploy it caused the problem. Thank you so much!